# changing Backgroundcolor of a single View in a ListView despite scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an Activity which is supposed to show one big ListView. Now I want to set the background colors of single lines. I tried to do it with getChildAt but then I can only mark those lines that are visible. So it doesnt work anymore, when the List is bigger than the screen. I could not figure out a working alternative, so I would be really glad if you could give me some advice.

Comment: Listview draws the children as they come on screen for performance.. Why would you want to set background color of the child which is not visible?

Comment: Ok, let me explain: I have a List with an onclick listener. The last item is special and changes the behavior of the onclick listener. I want to underline this changed behavior with changing the background color of the affected items. With the getChildAt I only get to change those lines that are visible right now. When I scroll up again the previously invisible Items won't be colored.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved from within the adapter of your ListView. In the `getView(...)` method check whether the current item matches your criteria of a single line, and if so then set the specific background color for the current row, otherwise set the default color.

Something like this:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // ....
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
      // ...

      Item item = items.get(position);
      if(item.isSingleLine()){
         convertView.setBackgroundColor(SINGLE_LINE_BG_COLOR);
      }else{
         convertView.setBackgroundColor(DEFAULT_BG_COLOR);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was quite easy using the Adapter, I just didn't think about that. It somehow feels a bit clunky this way, because when I use onclicklistener my only solution was to set the adapter again, but I think that's fine.